# ServletContextListener or load-on-startup is first executed?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm introducing ServletContextListener in a legacy application which uses a servlet's init() method and load-on-startup. My logger in the listener did not log as the initialization was in the init() of the servlet and apparently it was not yet initialized. Technically, which is first initialized ? ServletContextListener or servlet init ? Can I safely move logger initialization to listener ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()` is called before filters and servlets are initialized.

See the [servlet spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/servlet-3_1-final.pdf), chapter 10.12.